# Prove that the product of eigenvalues is equal to the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I saw [these notes](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eclayton/teaching/m215s10/homework/hw9solutions.pdf) (page 5, question 6) on proving that

$$\det(A) = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$$

where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are all the eigenvalues of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I am pasting the proof below for easier reference.

I followed the proof up until the point it set $\lambda = 0$. I don't understand the logic (paraphrased based on my interpretation) "because $\lambda$ is an abstract variable, we can set it to $0$." Doesn't setting $\lambda = 0$ implicitly mean that $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

---

[image]

Comment: It's saying that we can plug $\lambda = 0$ into the polynomial on the right to obtain $\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$. We're always free to evaluate a polynomial at any point and see what result we get. The trouble is that if $f(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I)$ it doesn't follow that $f(0) = \det A$. Or at least it reminds me of a widely circulated fake proof of cayley hamilton, so it needs some justification.

Comment: On second thought, I think it's fully rigorous. So, to clarify, the idea is just that we set $f(\lambda) = \det (A - \lambda I)$ and notice that, on the one hand, $f(0) = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$ (strictly speaking we should prove that $f(\lambda)$ is monic first). On the other hand, $f(0) = \det A$, so $\det A = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$.

Comment: The map $\lambda \to \det(A-\lambda I)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree $n$. The question supposes that this polynomial is given by $(\lambda_1 -\lambda) \cdots (\lambda_n -\lambda)$. So, setting $\lambda = 0$ we get $\det A = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$. That is all there is to it.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Just to clarify, $f(0) = \det A$ right,, which is what your second comment shows, but not the first?

Comment: On the one hand $f(0) = \det A$. On the other hand $f(0) = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$. Therefore, $\det A = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$. This is a common mathematical trick: find an equation of functions and then deduce an identity by plugging in a particular value and simplifying.

Comment: Something does still bother me though. We know from general principles that $\det(A - \lambda I) = c(\lambda_1 - \lambda) \cdots (\lambda_n - \lambda)$ for some $c$ and some $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. What, other than direct computation, assures us that $c = 1$?

Answer (score 2):

There is abuse by notation above.
$\lambda_i$ in the proof are the eigenvalues; $\lambda$ is a parameter.
Notice that when $\lambda = \lambda_i$ you get $\det (A-\lambda_iI) = 0$, meaning $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue indeed.
A general case may involve $\lambda_i = 0$, and it is still true.

Comment: This is not an abuse of notations. $\lambda$ and $\lambda_i$ are two different symbols in the first place.

Comment: You mean when $\lambda = \lambda_i$, you get $\det(A - \lambda_i I) = 0$, right, and not $\det A = 0$?